# Background image margin UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, background, margin

How to margin background image on UserControl, i want to margin 5pt from right but i dont know how to do it, i use C#. Can you help me whith this matter?

Answer (score 0):

if you are created the image dynamically you may try this

```
Image img = new Image();
img.CssClass = ".image";
```

and then use the defined cssclass .image

```
.image{
margin-right: 5pt;

     }
```

Comment: It is not a solution, i need to margin UserControl.BackgroundImage